# mutate_if for numeric colums divided by rowsums

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am just looking for an elegant 1 liner which would do division of each numeric column by the rowsums of these numeric columns. I would like to use mutate_if just don't know how the syntax should  be

```
data<-data.frame(date=seq(from=as.Date('2020-01-01'),to=as.Date('2020-01-05'),by="days"),
             a=sample(1:10,5),
             b=sample(1:10,5),
             c=sample(1:10,5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
data[i1] <- data[i1]/rowSums(data[i1])
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(tmp = select(., where(is.numeric)) %>%
      rowSums, across(where(is.numeric), ~ ./tmp), tmp = NULL)
```